# How can I use substr on json object with for loop?

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, substr, text-parsing

Could someone help on how to loop over response while using substr to get each variable. The variables would be Amount, Type, Balance, Date.

I have the json response

```
[
    [
        "AmountTypeBalanceDate",
        "$27.90Debit$6.3011/22/22, 3:32 PM",
        "$30.00Credit$34.2011/22/22, 5:13 PM",
        "$27.90Debit$4.209/12/22, 4:01 PM",
        "$30.00Credit$32.109/12/22, 8:49 PM",
        "$27.90Debit$2.107/20/22, 10:23 AM",
        "$30.00Credit$30.007/20/22, 3:22 PM",
        "Balance: $200.30"
    ]
]
```

Here is my code

```
if (xhr.status == 200) {
    console.log("status 200");
    var parsedWalletResult = JSON.parse(this.response);
    console.log(parsedWalletResult.values[0][2]); //Get the second value
    
    // Get the amount from the second  
    var walletAmount = parsedWalletResult.values[0][2]
    walletAmount = walletAmount.substr(0, 5);
    console.log("The wallet amount is: " +  walletAmount);// The wallet amount is: $30.0
    

    
    // loop over the parsed json response
    for (const key in parsedWalletResult){
      if(parsedWalletResult.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        console.log(`${key} : ${parsedWalletResult[key]}`)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why your server not send a json response with proper properties like `{Amount: "", Type: "", Balance: "", Date: ""}`, that should be the place you fix it instead of processing it like you described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `substr()` if the length of your fields differ ("Debit" vs "Credit"), at least not without hassle (i.e. trying out values until one matches).

You could use a regex though:

```js
const data = [
    [
        "AmountTypeBalanceDate",
        "$27.90Debit$6.3011/22/22, 3:32 PM",
        "$30.00Credit$34.2011/22/22, 5:13 PM",
        "$27.90Debit$4.209/12/22, 4:01 PM",
        "$30.00Credit$32.109/12/22, 8:49 PM",
        "$27.90Debit$2.107/20/22, 10:23 AM",
        "$30.00Credit$30.007/20/22, 3:22 PM",
        "Balance: $200.30"
    ]
]

const result = data.map(lines => lines.slice(1, -1).map(line => line.match(/(\$[0-9.]+)(\w+)(\$\d+\.\d{2})(.*)/).slice(1)))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect scenario for Regular Expressions. If you don't know regex, be careful, as this will be hard to maintain.

Here's my solution:

(possibly a more accurate regex than the other answer)

```
// I have removed the first and last elements so we just have data

const transactions = [
  "$27.90Debit$6.3011/22/22, 3:32 PM",
  "$30.00Credit$34.2011/22/22, 5:13 PM",
  "$27.90Debit$4.209/12/22, 4:01 PM",
  "$30.00Credit$32.109/12/22, 8:49 PM",
  "$27.90Debit$2.107/20/22, 10:23 AM",
  "$30.00Credit$30.007/20/22, 3:22 PM",
];

const transactionsAsObjects = transactions.map((transaction) => {
  const pattern =
    /(\$\d+\.\d+)(\w+)(\$\d+\.\d{2})(\d{1,2}?\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2}, \d{1,2}:\d{2} (AM|PM))/g;
  const match = pattern.exec(transaction);
  if (!match) return null;
  return {
    balance: match[1],
    type: match[2],
    amount: match[3],
    date: match[4],
  };
});

console.log(transactionsAsObjects);

/* 
  {balance: '$27.90', type: 'Debit', amount: '$6.30', date: '11/22/22, 3:32 PM'}
  {balance: '$30.00', type: 'Credit', amount: '$34.20', date: '11/22/22, 5:13 PM'}
  {balance: '$27.90', type: 'Debit', amount: '$4.20', date: '9/12/22, 4:01 PM'}
  {balance: '$30.00', type: 'Credit', amount: '$32.10', date: '9/12/22, 8:49 PM'}
  {balance: '$27.90', type: 'Debit', amount: '$2.10', date: '7/20/22, 10:23 AM'}
  {balance: '$30.00', type: 'Credit', amount: '$30.00', date: '7/20/22, 3:22 PM'}
*/
```